# Why do sounds get distorted when playing them multiple times?

Tags: core-audio, openal

When playing the same sound multiple times, it sounds OK the first time but becomes distorted (muted, as if it was far away) the next times. I'm playing from the same buffer (initialized once from a .wav file on startup) using openAL. Weirdly, the same happens when playing the sound in Apple apps (Xcode, Quicktime Player, Safari) but not in many third party apps (VLC, Chrome,...). Same code works fine on iOS, and the same sound file is also played correctly in the old Carbon version of the app on MacOS.

One of the sounds that exhibits the problem is http://www.colibricks.com/Sound131.wav.
You can hear it for yourself by opening that link in Safari and pressing the Play button. The first time it sounds OK, the next times it's like it's really far away. Reload the page, and it sounds OK again the first time you try, then far away again.
Open the same page in Chrome, though, and it sounds OK every time.

Strangely, the old compiled 32-bit Carbon version, which I can no longer compile in current versions of XCode but which was using the same sound files, sounds fine!

I have tried opening the file in Audacity, exporting it in many different formats (wav, aiff, 16 or 32 bit,...), and playing those files in Quicktime Player. Always the same result: first play OK, then distorted.

This is the code I'm using to play the sounds (after having set up all the sources and buffers in pretty much the standard way)

```
alSourcef(source[i], AL_GAIN, volume * (1.f/256.f));
alSourcei(source[i], AL_BUFFER, 0);
alSourcei(source[i], AL_BUFFER, bufID[which-128]);
alSourcePlay(source[i]);
```

There seems to be some kind of bug in openAL or some other part of the audio system that deforms sounds when they are played repeatedly, not just in my app but in other Apple apps too.

I would like to try other solutions to play the sounds (openAL is being deprecated anyway) but am having a hard time finding simple sample code for CoreAudio or AudioAVEngine that just plays sounds at different volumes left and right (or extremely basic panning). My needs are really simple: load a bunch of very short sounds into buffers, then play them at different volumes left/right during the game. No special 3d effects and reverbs and all that stuff. I'm kind of afraid of going through all the work to implement AudioAVEngine only to find out that the problem remains. And CoreAudio seems a bit daunting, unless someone can point me to some good usable code for that? And will that fix the distorted sound?